# C# Regex Any Number twince

Tags: c#, regex

I want to delete the "**, 2**" here doing Regex, how am I doing that?

This way: CreatePickup(anynumber)(anynumber, **2**

```
CreatePickup0(1240, 2, 1693.0444, -1959.2195, 8.2500, -1);

CreatePickup1(5243, 2, 1693.0444, -1959.2195, 8.2500, -1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method if you must use a regular expression.

Simplest way is to use a [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to retain the part you want to keep.

```
String s = "CreatePickup0(1240, 2, 1693.0444, -1959.2195, 8.2500, -1);";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"(CreatePickup\d+\(\d+), *\d+", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "CreatePickup0(1240, 1693.0444, -1959.2195, 8.2500, -1);"
```

If this is always the format of the string, you could modify it as follows:

```
String r = Regex.Replace(s, "^([^,]+),[^,]+", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex and C# you can use:

```
string newstring = null;
    try {
        newstring = Regex.Replace(oldstring, @"(?!CreatePickup\d+\(\d+), 2,(?=.*?;)", ",");
    } catch (ArgumentException ex) {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a look behind you can use

```
(?<=CreatePickup\d\(\d+,\s*)\d
```

I've tested the regex on the 2 examples you included.

alternatively you can replace from the start of the string using

```
(CreatePickup\d\(\d+,\s*)\d
```

this will just remove the 2

```
Regex.Replace("CreatePickup0(1240, 2, 1693.0444, -1959.2195, 8.2500, -1);", @"(CreatePickup\d\(\d+,\s*)\d", "$1");
```

results in "CreatePickup0(1240, , 1693.0444, -1959.2195, 8.2500, -1);"